# Axios: XSRF Cookie not being sent with request in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, cookies, axios

I have VueJS frontend talking to a Rails backend. I can successfully create [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLTGj.jpg)  a session and receive the CSRF token to store, but it's never sent [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5QNl.png) in subsequent Axios requests when deployed on Heroku. It works fine on localhost, and both the frontend + backend are hosted on herokuapp.com so SameSite shouldn't be an issue.

Axios is set to include the XSRF token with requests:

```
const API_URL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL || "http://localhost:8080";
axios.defaults.baseURL = API_URL;
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "CSRF-TOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRF-Token";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

How can I ensure Axios passes this cookie to my Rails Application? Images below: cookie returned on session creation and then not included in the following request.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLTGj.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue with .herokuapp.com being on the public suffix list. Adding a custom domain solved the issue.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing issues with Axios not sending the CSRF token in requests when deployed, especially if you're using subdomains of platforms like `herokuapp.com` or `netlify.app`, the problem might be related to how cookies are handled on these public domains.

**The Root Cause:**
Domains like `herokuapp.com` and `netlify.app` are on the Public Suffix List, a list maintained by the Mozilla Foundation. Browsers use this list to restrict certain behaviors around cookies to enhance user privacy and security. Specifically, cookies set for a specific subdomain (e.g., `yourapp.herokuapp.com` or `yourapp.netlify.app`) might not be easily set or read by other subdomains or even the same subdomain in some cases.

**Why it works on localhost:**
When you're working on `localhost`, these restrictions don't apply, which is why everything works as expected. But on a live environment, especially on shared domains like `.netlify.app`, these restrictions can come into play.

**Solution:**
The most straightforward solution is to use a custom domain for both your frontend and backend. This ensures that you have full control over the cookies and their behaviors. Once you set up a custom domain, you can configure it in both your frontend and backend settings.

In my case, after switching to a custom Apex domain (`https://example.com`), everything started working perfectly. Axios was able to send the CSRF token in the header to the Laravel backend without any issues.

**Steps to Address:**

1. **Custom Domain**: Purchase and set up a custom domain for your application. Platforms like Heroku and Netlify have documentation to guide you through this process.
2. **Update Configurations**: Ensure that your frontend and backend configurations are updated to use the new custom domain.
3. **Test**: After setting up the custom domain, test the functionality that was previously failing. It should now work as expected.

**Conclusion:**
While platforms like Heroku and Netlify offer great convenience, their subdomains come with certain restrictions due to security and privacy concerns. Using a custom domain is the recommended solution to ensure consistent and expected behavior across all environments.

I hope this helps anyone facing a similar issue. It's essential to understand the underlying behavior of cookies on public domains and how it can affect your application's functionality.